# How to autoscroll Custom Table View cell in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to auto scroll table view cell.
I am using code like this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  [table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, table.contentSize.height - table.bounds.size.height)
                 animated:YES]; 

  [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[headarray count]-1 inSection:0]                                                
                   atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                           animated:YES];
}
```

But it shows me bad access what I am doing wrong in this code.Thanks in Advance!

I have Try your code like this in connectionDidFinishLoading method

```
if ([headarray count] != 0) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[headarray count]-1 inSection:0];
            [Newstable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
        }
```

Comment: Your code is absolutely right but check this `[musicGenre count]-1 inSection:0]` , what it is returning, check its value and class.

Comment: @muja try my code and just remove your [table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, table.contentSize.height - table.bounds.size.height)
                 animated:YES]; this line

Comment: @Muju Do you want to scroll at last row of table like chat ?

Comment: Which is your data source array? `headarray` or `musicGenre `?

Comment: @PiyushPatel Head array is my data source array.

Comment: Then you have passed `musicGenre` array in `viewDidAppear ` method

Comment: @PiyushPatel Sorry I update question.

Comment: @Muju did you tried without setting `setContentOffset`? and What's the IndexPath count you getting?

Comment: @PiyushPatel No not tried without  setContentOffset

Comment: @Muju Then try and and tell the count of index path you getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link https://github.com/danielamitay/DAAutoScroll. You can use these classes to autoscroll your tableview. 
1. Import class

## import "DAAutoScroll.h"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollDown) withObject:self afterDelay:3.0];
}

-(void)scrollDown{

    yourtableview.scrollPointsPerSecond = 20.0f;
    [yourtableview startScrolling];

}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate) {
        [yourtableview startScrolling];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [yourtableview startScrolling];
}
```

Comment: In demo it work perfect but when I used it in project it not work.

Comment: @Muju What is the issue when you try to use that in project?

Comment: @Muju Thant means you don't know how to implement it in your project coz its not possible that demo is working perfect but in your project its not working.

Comment: @PiyushPatel I have used custom table view cell and I implement it in my project. Yes may be I am doing something wrong while implementing it.

Comment: @Muju : that doesn't matter that you are using custom cell or  not.

Answer (score 0):

```
[tableviewname setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, ([arrayofcontact count]-10)*cellheight) animated:YES];
```

Comment: What does this code do and why does it solve the problem?